# show the sum of a specific variety to another table sql

Tags: sql

Table Inventory

```
|Variety|Weight|Quantity|
|-------|--------|------|
|Native Chicken|1.6kg|10|
|Native Chicken|1.3|20|
|Chicken Broiler|2.1|30|
|Chicken Broiler|2.3|10|
|Duck|2.1|30|
|Duck|2.3|15|
|Turkey|2.1|30|
|Turkey|2.3|15|
```

How to get this desired Output for table Reports using the SELECT WHERE, Join and Sum statement in SQL. I've been trying to solve this for a few days now but I haven't seen any codes to answer for this one. Can you help your girl out? Thanks!

Table Reports

```
|Variety|Qty|
|-------|---|
|Native Chicken|30|
|Chicken Broiler|40|
|Duck|45|
|Turkey|45|
```

this is the code that I've tried but it's not working.

```
INSERT INTO reports(qty)
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM (SELECT Inventory.Quantity = "Native Chicken" FROM InventoryTable);
```

Comment: Why is it not working?  What part?  That will help us help you.

Comment: _not working_ - does that mean wrong result, or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sum the quantity and group by the column that represents each quantity.

The `group by` "groups" all like values together where you then `sum` the quantites for each into a single value

```
insert into Reports (Variety, Qty)    
select Variety, sum(Quantity) 
from Inventory
group by Variety
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this one and I'd like to ask how do you stop from duplicating the data inside the database every time the form loads?

Comment: I have no idea what your code is doing. Look into `exists()` in sql

Comment: Hi! Here's the link since I cant comment out here the whole code that I've been using  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691145/how-to-stop-duplicating-the-data-in-database-everytime-the-form-loads

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`:

```
insert into Reports (Variety, Qty)

select Variety, sum(Quantity) as Qty
from Inventory
group by Variety
```

However, I'd consider a view instead of a Reports table, because a view will always have up-to-date data. A separate table requires being emptied and inserted into over and over again.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this one and I'd like to ask how do you stop from duplicating the data inside the database every time the form loads?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO reports
SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety;
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this one and I'd like to ask how do you stop from duplicating the data inside the database every time the form loads?

Comment: Don't run the query on form load but somewhere else.