# How to stop duplicating the data in database everytime the form loads?

Tags: c#, database

I am currently making a system where one of the requirements is to generate a report for the total number of products available in the inventory.

I've been using this code to get the sum of the quantity of each variety in the database table.

```
public void ShowData()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=JAPoultry;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Reports", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgv_Reports.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void frmReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=JAPoultry;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Reports (Variety, Quantity) SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ShowData();


    }
```

but my problem is every time the form loads, the data is duplicating or keeps on adding onto the database.

Comment: So ... don't execute the INSERT INTO statement? What exactly is the question here?

Comment: If you keep pressing the button labelled "INSERT" then inserts will keep happening.

Comment: The data grid view should load all the data every time the form loads. My question here is how to stop adding the data repeatedly into the database since that INSERT INTO statement is for solving the sum of the total number of quantity of a specific variety of products.

Comment: Why can't you just do a `SELECT` and fetch the results instead of `INSERT`? It's not clear why that part is necessary.

Comment: Oh okay! I get the logic but since I am new with the SQL and C# language that's why I am having trouble with it. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: sure,.. I 'll use 2 querys  one for insert only the new records, and the second to update the olds and keeping   almos your original code 
´ string ins="INSERT INTO Reports (Variety, Quantity) SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety" +
   " WHERE Variety not in (select Variety from reports)";
 string upd="UPDATE Reports set quuantity=x.q from (SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) as q "+ ´
   " FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety) x where Reports.Variety=x.Variety"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand  the need of your "reports" table,... If I was you I'll use only ShowData()  with the query, like this

```
public void ShowData()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=JAPoultry;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgv_Reports.DataSource = dt;
    }
    private void frmReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowData();
    }
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this one already but the SUM of the quantity is not showing. :(

Comment: aaah ok... that is because the alias of the sum,   ... do this " SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity"   thats all

Comment: Is there a way that I can store it to my database table once a I made a changes with my Inventory data?

Comment: On the load event put this

con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=JAPoultry;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
 cmd = new SqlCommand"INSERT INTO Reports (Variety, Quantity) SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety WHERE Variety not in (select Variety from reports)",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Reports set quuantity=x.q from (SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) as q FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety) x where Reports.Variety=x.Variety", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close()

ShowData();

Answer (score 0):

Move the INSERT command into a new InsertData() method and call this method when required rather than each time frmReports_Load is called.

Comment: I am not using any buttons for this one and that INSERT INTO statement is for solving the sum of the total number of quantity of a specific variety of products.

Comment: You currently do the duplication on any load of the window, hence the data is duplicated. You should either adjust your INSERT INTO to check for existing data or do this manually.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I'll try this one out as well!

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `frmReports_Load` method run `SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety` only, and display the result directly on the screen each time the form loads, if that's what you need.

This is what I mean - you might just need to add an alias to the SUM column so it maps into your gridview correctly:

```
public void ShowData()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=JAPoultry;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dgv_Reports.DataSource = dt;
}

private void frmReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowData();
}
```

---

P.S. It's unclear why you're inserting that data into another table - unless you need to keep a log of every single time someone loaded a form? That seems a little unlikely as a requirement, to be honest.

Comment: I'd tried this and it works perfectly but the data is not storing in the database.

Comment: Yes that's because we removed the INSERT command. You said you didn't want it to be stored on the database anymore!

Comment: And you don't need to store it anyway, because the information already exists in your tables. You can simply calculate it anytime you need it, which is exactly what this code is doing.